# Change the content inside DIV based on href link containing child DIV with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I wasn't sure how to set a title for this question.

What I want is to change content inside a DIV with the content of clicked `<a>` tag. The problem is that inside my `<a>` tag I have another nested DIV with some text, and I don't want that text to be displayed on change.

How to display only the content of `<a>` tag on change, without its child div?

Here's my code and link to JSFiddle

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a.dropdown__link', function() {
  $('.dropdown__label').text($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-tabs="" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation">
    <a data-tabby-default="" href="#seo" class="heading-4 dropdown__link">
                        SEO
                        <div class="tabs-card__tab-subtitle">Description 1</div>
                     </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#web" class="heading-4 dropdown__link">
                        Web
                        <div class="tabs-card__tab-subtitle">Description 2</div>
                     </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#marketing" class="heading-4 dropdown__link">
                        Social
                        <div class="tabs-card__tab-subtitle">Description 3</div>
                     </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#marketingppc" class="heading-4 dropdown__link">
                        PPC
                        <div class="tabs-card__tab-subtitle">Description 4</div>
                     </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="dropdown__label">Default text</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mariokala/zmdjoy9b/28/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7qn6wodu/

Answer (score 2):

Update your click event like so;

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a.dropdown__link', function(){
    $('.dropdown__label').text($(this).contents().not($(this).children()).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-tabs="" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation">
    <a data-tabby-default="" href="#seo" class="heading-4 dropdown__link" id="tabby-toggle_think" role="tab" aria-controls="seo" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
                        SEO
                        <div class="tabs-card__tab-subtitle">Description 1</div>
                     </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#web" class="heading-4 dropdown__link" id="tabby-toggle_execute" role="tab" aria-controls="web" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">
                        Web
                        <div class="tabs-card__tab-subtitle">Description 2</div>
                     </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#marketing" class="heading-4 dropdown__link" id="tabby-toggle_manage" role="tab" aria-controls="marketing" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">
                        Social
                        <div class="tabs-card__tab-subtitle">Description 3</div>
                     </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#marketingppc" class="heading-4 dropdown__link" id="tabby-toggle_manage" role="tab" aria-controls="marketingppc" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">
                        PPC
                        <div class="tabs-card__tab-subtitle">Description 4</div>
                     </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="dropdown__label">Default text</div>
```